# State Of Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

In "edmx" page I have button control with event "NextButton_Click" for click. When I click this button the variables "index" doesn't want to change to "40" and the "text"
 variable doesn't want to change to "active". These variables are always in the same state "text" is always equal to "start" and "index" is always equal to "10". Why they don't want to change with (index = 40;
 text = "active";) as I wrote in the click button event method ?

```
public partial class CountriesTowns : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int index = 10;
    string text = "start";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            index = 20;
            text = "stop";
        }
    }

    //click next button
    protected void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        Response.Write(index);
        Response.Write(text);
        index = 40;
        text = "active";
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you make them public? Probably they cannot be serialized to the viewstate and so can't be read back in on the postback.

Comment: @Lloyd: Variables are disposed at the end of the life-cycle. You have to put them into ViewState manually(or use controls which use ViewState) to persist them.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I knew there was a reason I always avoided using it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP is stateless, every object like your  `index` or `text`(and even all controls) are destroyed at the end of the page's life-cycle. So they are always initialized with their default value.

```
int index = 10;
string text = "start";
```

You can use a control(f.e. a `TextBox` or a `HiddenField`) to persist their value across postbacks.

But there are other options:

[**Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Comment: I found on internet that I can use ViewState Dictionary to save my information across postbacks. Am I on the right way ?

Comment: @TheChampp: Yes, that might be a good way. Add a property `Index` and `Text` to your page which returns(and sets) the value in a `ViewState` variable like `ViewState["index"] = 10;`. If you want to learn more(you ever wanted to learn), read this: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are not persisting the updated state of the `index` and `text` variables between post backs. As such, since a new instance of `CountriesTowns` is created per request, the values are re-initialised to their default values.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you click a button, you cause what is known as a *Postback*. A Postback does not just run your click code... it also rebuilds your *entire* page. To do this, *it creates a brand new instance of your Page class*, which is then destroyed as soon as the html for your new page is completed. It has to do this because the original instance of your Page class was also destroyed as soon the html was rendered.